# Installing Armadillo on macOS with homebrew

Tags: c++, c++11, armadillo

I am trying to install Armadillo with Homebrew with

```
brew install armadillo
```

but when I try to compile with

```
g++ example.cpp -o example -std=c++11 -O2 -larmadillo
```

it gives the following error:

```
fatal error: 'armadillo' file not found
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please include in your question the **complete** error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here that you have a new M1 Mac. The issue in this case is that ARM-native homebrew is installed to /opt/homebrew/ by default, meaning armadillo was installed to /opt/homebrew/include/ which is not in your search path.

To see if this is the case, try providing the paths as follows:

```
CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib g++ example.cpp -o example -std=c++11 -O2 -larmadillo
```

To avoid the issue in general, I'm running with those CPATH and LIBRARY_PATH variables exported in my `~/.zprofile` file (using `zsh`). I found [this answer on the apple stack exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414622/installing-a-c-c-library-with-homebrew-on-m1-macs) helpful.